# What does it mean when a macro store the values inside his own arguments?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, x86

`rdtsc` is used to atomically read the 64-bit counter register in the Linux kernel (TSC) into two 32-bit variables. I read Linux Device Drivers 3 and it says that this macro store the values (`low32` and `high32`) into his own arguments, but as you can see `rdtsc` takes `void`

- What does "*macro store the value into his arguments*" mean, and how can I get that variables?
- What does `DECLARE_ARGS` do?

```
#define DECLARE_ARGS(val, low, high)    unsigned long low, high

static __always_inline unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
    DECLARE_ARGS(val, low, high);

    // ...

    return EAX_EDX_VAL(val, low, high);
}
```

I know it does not make sense but I do what the book says it does

```
long long x, y;
rdtsc(x, y); // store the values into his arguments
```

Comment: Are you sure the book refers to the Linux kernel function? Couldn't it just be pseudo code or referring to some other API?

Comment: As for `DECLARE_ARGS` it apparently picks the appropriate 64 bit type depending on build & compiler (size of long). Before `#define DECLARE_ARGS` there's a `#ifdef CONFIG_X86_64`. A comment in the source says /* Using 64-bit values saves one instruction clearing the high half of low */.

Comment: Are you sure it hasn't changed since the book was written?

Comment: @user253751 Probably, that is why I am asking. The actual code is taking from the latest kernel source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you posted `rdtsc` is a function, not a macro. `DECLARE_ARGS` is a macro and it simply defines two variables (`low` and `high`) of type `unsigned long`. The function will return the TSC value. You didn't include the `EAX_EDX_VAL` macro, so here it is:

```c
#define EAX_EDX_VAL(val, low, high) ((low) | (high) << 32)
```

So the function `rdtsc` will read the low and high parts of the TSC into the local variables `low` and `high` and will return a 64-bit value composed from the two 32-bit values.

One could use the function like this

```c
unsigned long tsc = rdtsc();
```

You can see how it is used inside the Linux kernel by looking at the [Referenced section here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/C/ident/rdtsc).

Comment: Hey, thanks. The book says that `rdtsc` is a macro found in `asm/msr.h`. And yeah I know what `rdtsc` does. Now I understand what `DECLARE_ARGS` does thank to you. Now my question is how can I access `low` and `high`? Also, I took the examples from the link you provided

Comment: You can't access `low` and `high`. Those are local variables for the `rdtsc` function, and only `rdtsc` has access to them. But why do you want to access them anyway?

Comment: I don't, just curious. Thanks!